# discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions error for setting up roles

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord

I am trying to setup roles for my discord bot but keep getting this error:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013)
```

My Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   guild = client.get_guild(688568885968109756)
   role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=689916456871133311)
   await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Does your bot have the manage_roles permission?  Is the role you're trying to add higher in the role hierarchy than the bots highest role?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your bot have enough permission, Then it's coming due to the hierarchy of roles.
Check-in server settings for the hierarchy.

For changing the hierarchy, you can move the roles up down in the settings.

Comment: @Bhalo Kumar thank you so much. You are life saver... The hierarchy would never come to my mind.. Very weird.. But thank you so much