# I Get an error code saying my bot has missing permissions but it has administrator when trying to give someone a role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=902678566808997898)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

On the Oauth2 it has administrator, i add it to my server and when someone joins, it gives me the error

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I undid the solution announcement by rolling back. If you also added/improved other information than the solution they are gone along with that. In that case please take my apology, I might have been a little quick. The info is not lost, you can still find everything in the edit history (just above my user name and symbol mentioning me as the currently most recent editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by moving the bot's role to the top ranked role, this gave the bot the permissions to change someone's role.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You say you have Oauth2 correct sections enabled, but have you enabled manage roles in bot permissions in section 'bot' in the developer portal?

Comment: Oh Im sorry, didnt realise i needed to enable that in bot too, thanks

Comment: turns out i still get the same error "discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions"

Comment: I believe this will solve your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128637/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions