# discord.py get guild members

Tags: python, discord

I'm creating a bot in discord.py and I am creating a command to kick all non-roled server members.

The problem however is, I see the bot as the only member. I tried researching the docs, but I couldn't find a clear example or answer.

Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick_non_role(ctx, *, reason=None):
  print(ctx.guild.members)
  for member in ctx.guild.members:
      print(member)
      if len(member._roles) == 1:
          await member.kick(reason='No role assigned')
          print(f'Non-roled members have been kicked from the server.')
      print(f'{member} has roles: {len(member._roles)}')
```

Here's the output:

```
[<Member id=904484713937379390 name='Bouncer_Bot' discriminator='5970' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=867621531320057887 name='SixtyNiners' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=10>>]
Bouncer_Bot#5970
Bouncer_Bot#5970 has roles: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nyghi for posting the thread. My issue was hierarchy of roles in my server, set the bot role to the top and my code went to work.

[discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions error for setting up roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128637/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing `Member Intents` to see the members of a `guild` and this is probably the reason you are only getting your bot in a server.

Discord.py has it is own explanation about this topic that you can read [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

Answer (score 0):

My first question is if the Discord bot has the permissions it needs to view all members and kick them. Emphasis on view all members permission.

Comment: In the permissions, I see no 'view all members' option.

Has all text permissions and all admin permissions other than:
Administrator
View Audit
Manage server

Can you clarify what you mean?